# Why does my localStorage.setItem not seem to be doing anything?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I have tried to simplify the code down to what is relevant.

```
class AnnotatedLayout extends React.Component {
    state = {
        user: '',
        enabled: false,
    };

    render() {
        const { user, enabled } = this.state;
        const contentStatus = enabled ? 'Disable' : 'Enable';
        const textStatus = enabled ? 'enabled' : 'disabled';

        return (
            ...
                            <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                                <FormLayout>
                                    <TextField
                                        value={user}
                                        onChange={this.handleChange('user')}
                                        label="Shop Name"
                                        type="user"
                                        helpText={
                                            <span>
                                                Log in with your store username.
                                            </span>
                                        }
                                    />
                                    <Stack distribution="trailing">
                                        <Button primary submit>
                                            Submit
                                        </Button>
                                    </Stack>
                                </FormLayout>
                            </Form>
                        ...
        );
    }
    handleSubmit = () => {
        this.setState({
            user: this.state.user
        });
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.state.user));
        console.log('submission', this.state);
        console.log(this.state.user);
    };
    handleChange = field => {
        return value => this.setState({ [field]: value });
    };
}

export default AnnotatedLayout;
```

Essentially, I have a form component to my webpage that, on submitting, is executing this.handleSubmit, and that function is at the bottom.

**What my code SHOULD be doing is saving that submitted string to the localStorage with the key 'user', but evidently (you can see below console.log output) that's not happening.**

Any idea what's going on?

[image]

My website is hosted locally, tunneled to a URL, and used as the base URL for a shopify embedded app, just to give all relevant context.

**UPDATE**

```
handleSubmit = () => {
    this.setState({
        user: this.state.user
    },
        () => localStorage.setItem('user', "SMH"),
        console.log(localStorage.getItem('user'))
        );
    console.log('submission', this.state);
};
```

Check this out, after submitting my text form now this is what I get

[image]

is localStorage like local or something, to the point where it doesnt save anything outside of a function??

Comment: `this.setState({ user: this.state.user })` ... what, why?

Comment: Have you tried removing `JSON.stringify` from `localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(this.state.user))`? It's already a string...

Comment: i'm following a tutorial at the moment, and that's what they had. @user633183

Comment: Would you post code for `this.handleChange?

Comment: @JackBashford, I have tried that as well, and since it didn't work, I tried it with the JSON.stringify, but I just ran it without the stringify and it's the same result, null :/

Comment: @SungKim just updated

Comment: @adiga I know handlesubmit is being called because the console.log output is showing up from inside the handleSubmit function, and the output is from me trying to submit on the live app

Comment: Have you tried running `localStorage.setItem('user', 'foobar')` in the browser? Does that work?

Comment: @putvande yes, doing it manually from the browser console works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you `handleChange` returns a method, which you need to call again to set the user value.

Instead of

```js
<TextField
   value={user}
   onChange={this.handleChange('user')}
...
```

Try

```js
<TextField
   value={user}
   onChange={e => this.handleChange('user')(e)}
...
```

The `value` in `handleChange` should accept `e` event value, which is the user value to set.

Comment: Would it not be `e.target.value` or something? Guess it depends what that `onChange` of `TextField` returns. On the other hand, OP logs out `this.state.user` so the `handleChange` must work?

Comment: Okay, I see what you were trying to say and the textfield changes should have sufficed, which i have tried, but with no success :/

Comment: @putvande yeah. that `e.target.value` need to be transformed as a `user` object. But the code doesn't seem to have that step... 

Comment: @ark0n I will close the issue later in case you need it later. 

Answer (score -1):

```
this.setState(
  {
    user: this.state.user
  },
  () => localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.state.user))
);
```

Comment: I tried this and getItem still returns null, with and without json.stringify fwiw

Comment: @ark0n This is right. You don't seem to understand how state works in React components. First, you're just setting the state of `user` back to its current state, so nothing will change. More importantly, `setState` does not immediately change `this.state` on a component. It triggers off a new render cycle, so the updated state will next be available in `componentWillUpdate` (note this is becoming deprecated soon). However, you can add the extra callback function that is always executed after the state updates. https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous